# How to apply filtering from multiple div element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn `javascript` filtering. But there are some good examples for filtering from the list elements of the page, but how can I filter an entire `div` based on the search input?

This is so far I have done, but I'm stuck and not sure how to proceed further, I hope you'll be kind enough to help me learn the process, thanks in advance.

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lew3sjyr/14/) and the snippet is given below:

```js
const searchBar = document.forms['search-books'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    const term = e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase();
    const books = list.getElementsByTagName('h5');
    Array.from(books).forEach(function(books) {
        const title = book.firstElementChild.textContent;
        if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
            book.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            book.style.display = 'none';
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form id="search-books">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search a book ... ">
</form>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row list-single">
      <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1447303603s/2767052.jpg"/></div>
      <div class="col-10">
         <h5> The Hunger Games</h5>
         <a href="The-Hunger-Games.html">Learn</a> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row list-single">
      <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1507396732s/2.jpg"/></div>
      <div class="col-10">
         <h5>Harry Potter</h5>
         <a href="Harry-Potter.html">Learn</a> 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either declare the `list` element or get all the elements with Tag `h5`.

Since you want to hide or display the element, you should target the parent of the parent of the div with the given text.

```js
const searchBar = document.forms['search-books'].querySelector('input');
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    const term = e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase();
    const books = document.getElementsByTagName('h5');
    Array.from(books).forEach(function(book) {
        const title = book.textContent;
        if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
            book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'flex';
        } else {
            book.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form id="search-books">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search a book ... ">
</form>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row list-single">
      <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1447303603s/2767052.jpg"/></div>
      <div class="col-10">
         <h5> The Hunger Games</h5>
         <a href="The-Hunger-Games.html">Learn</a> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row list-single">
      <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1507396732s/2.jpg"/></div>
      <div class="col-10">
         <h5>Harry Potter</h5>
         <a href="Harry-Potter.html">Learn</a> 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. It's perfect. And also thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll('.container h5')` it will return array all `h5` tag inside of `container`.

**DEMO**

```js
const searchBar = document.forms['search-books'].querySelector('input'),
  books = document.querySelectorAll('.container h5');
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  
  let term = e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase();
  books.forEach(el => {
    let title = el.innerText;
    if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) != -1) {
   
      el.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      el.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form id="search-books">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search a book ... ">
</form>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row list-single">
    <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1447303603s/2767052.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <h5> The Hunger Games</h5>
      <a href="The-Hunger-Games.html">Learn</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row list-single">
    <div class="col-2"><img src="https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1507396732s/2.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <h5>Harry Potter</h5>
      <a href="Harry-Potter.html">Learn</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and explanation.